# rake db:migrate returns with error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, syntax-error

I ran rake db:migrate and I came across this error in terminal

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: admin_users: ALTER TABLE "admin_users" ADD "username" varchar(25)/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
```

I looked into my alter_user.rb file `class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration`

this is the file 20150825065823_alter_users.rb

```
def up
  rename_table("users", "admin_users.broken")
  add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25, :after => "email" )
  change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
  rename_column("admin_users", "broken", "hashed_password")
  puts "*** Adding an index is next ***"
  add_index("admin_users", "username")
end

def down
  remove_index("admin_users", "username")
  rename_column("admin_users", "hashed_password", "password")
  change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :default => "" , :null => false)
  remove_column("admin_users", "username")
  rename_table("admin_users", "users")
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `#up` method, you're adding columns to `admin_users` but you haven't defined that table yet.

Instead of:

`rename_table("users", "admin_users.broken")`

try:

`rename_table("users", "admin_users")`

Comment: It still says StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:No such column: admin_users.broken/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:490:in `column_for'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:497:in `rename_column'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:661:in `block in method_missing'

Comment: It's because you've already ran the migration with admin_users.broken as the name of the table. Replace the code back to `rename_table("users", "admin_users.broken")`, then do: `rake db:rollback`, then replace the code to: `rename_table("users", "admin_users")` and now migrate.